# Where is the .codenameone and the .cn1 folder in Linux?

Tags: codenameone

does anyone know where the .cn1 and the .codenameone folders are located in Linux?

I am using Netbeans IDE 10.0 in Ubuntu 18.10  need to access the simulator's storage and screenshots respectively.

Thanks, Tommy.

Comment: `find $HOME -name '.cn1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @fragmentedreality helped me locate the .cn1 and .codenameone folders. They are located in the user directory in the home folder as follows:

```
/home/username/.cn1 
/home/username/.codenameone
```

They are hidden folders and so have names that start with a . (dot character). To toggle show/hide hidden files or folders use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+H.